# Understanding simple lambdas with more than 1 parameters

Tags: java, lambda

I have reading about lambdas, and see sintax examples like these:

```
() -> true
a -> a.startWith("test")
(String a) -> a.startWith("test")
(a,b) -> a.startWith("test")
(String a, String b) -> a.startWith("test")
```

Ok, I read about Predicate interface and try make some little examples with a simple List of Strings. All work fine, but I can't understand this.

```
public class LambdaTests {
    public static void main(String...strings){

        List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("Hola");
        al.add("Que");
        al.add("Tal");
        al.add("Estas");
        al.add("Hoy");
        al.add("Machupichu");

        System.out.println(al);
        //al.removeIf(a -> a.contains("a"));
        //al.removeIf((String a) -> a.contains("a"));
        //al.removeIf((String a) -> { return a.contains("a");} );*/

        //al.removeIf((String a, String b) -> { return a.contains("a") || b.contains("a"); } ); NO COMPILE
        //predication(al, (a,b) -> a.contains("a") || b.contains("o")); No compile
        System.out.println(al);

    }

    public static void predication(ArrayList al, Predicate<String> checker){

    }
}
```

Really I don't know where is the origin of "b" in some cases, I only know removeIf method accepts a Predicate and I created another one (predication) But I don't know really wheres the origin to use more parameters in the lambda expression.

Any help?

Comment: A Predicate is a function that takes **1** argument, and returns a boolean. If you want a lambda that has two arguments, you need something other than a Predicate: a BiPredicate, or a BiFunction, or a BiConsumer, for example. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer- for an method that accepts such a thing.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You obviously see that it doesn't compile if you add a second parameter.  So there is no (can't be any) `b`. Please clarify.

Comment: Are you asking about those first examples? How are those related to your larger snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Supplier**

   ```
   () -> true
   ```

   This is not a predicate, but a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) (or `BooleanSupplier`). No parameters, a single return value.

---

2. **Predicate**

   ```
   a -> a.startWith("test")
   ```

   This is a `Predicate`. A single parameter, which returns a `boolean`.

---

3. **Predicate**

   ```
   (String a) -> a.startWith("test")
   ```

   Also a `Predicate`, but the input type being explicitly declared.

---

4. **BiPredicate**

   ```
   (a,b) -> a.startWith("test")
   ```

   Not a `Predicate`, but a [`BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html). It takes two parameters and returns a primitive `boolean`.

---

5. **BiPredicate**

   ```
   (String a, String b) -> a.startWith("test")
   ```

   Also a `BiPredicate`, but with its parameter types being explicit.

In your example, you're expecting a `Predicate`, but `(a, b) -> a.contains("a") || b.contains("o")` is a `BiPredicate` and thus won't compile. You could change your method to the following `public static void predication(List<String> al, BiPredicate<String, String> checker)`.

Also note that the parameter changed to `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`. Since your variable was declated as of type `List`.

Comment: I understand now, I was reading a OCA book and see all these examples but there aren't much info about these :) Now I know how create my customs Predicates. Thanks